# What happens to questions whose tags are burned down?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

I was wondering what happens to the questions whose tags are burned down, specially when there might only be one tag?

Comment: The real question is, what happens to the poor little tags that have been burninated? Do they go to tag heaven? Or is there a tag hell? Can they ever be reincarnated?

Comment: look there is a tag for tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are automatically "assigned" a special tag called [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged). They then have to be manually given more appropriate tags by an editor.

Comment: It's worth noting that burnination is often a manual process and it's impossible to manually remove the last tag without replacing it with another.